# Loop sum TimeSpan

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that calculates the `TimeSpan` of dates. I need to get the sum of 3 `TimeSpan`s and then get the sum of the next 3 etc.. till the last `timespan`.

This is my code so far:

I'm able to get the sum of the `TimeSpan`s but only the total of all sums and they are displayed wrong. Can someone help me with this?

```
Sub HoursCalculation()
    Dim textBoxes1A() As TextBox = {TextBox1, TextBox3, TextBox5, TextBox7, TextBox9, TextBox11}
    Dim textBoxes1B() As TextBox = {TextBox2, TextBox4, TextBox6, TextBox8, TextBox10, TextBox12}
    Dim textBoxesTOT() As TextBox = {TextBox221, TextBox222, TextBox223, TextBox224, TextBox225, TextBox226, TextBox227}
    Dim total As Date
    Dim ts1 As TimeSpan
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim t As Integer

    For i = 0 To textBoxes1A.Count - 1
        If IsDate(textBoxes1A(i).Text) AndAlso IsDate(textBoxes1B(i).Text) Then
            ts1 = DateTime.Parse(textBoxes1B(i).Text).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(textBoxes1A(i).Text))
            ' Add all the differences to a total
            total = total.Add(ts1)
            textBoxesTOT(t).Text = total
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Reset the value of `total` every 3 additions.
2. Increment the value of `t` every 3 additions.
3. (Preferably) Rather than using `IsDate()` and then `Parse`ing the value, you should use [`DateTime.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse) instead.

Your code should look something like this:

```
Sub HoursCalculation()
    Dim textBoxes1A() As TextBox = {TextBox1, TextBox3, TextBox5, TextBox7, TextBox9, TextBox11}
    Dim textBoxes1B() As TextBox = {TextBox2, TextBox4, TextBox6, TextBox8, TextBox10, TextBox12}
    Dim textBoxesTOT() As TextBox = {TextBox221, TextBox222, TextBox223, TextBox224, TextBox225,
                                     TextBox226, TextBox227}
    Dim total As TimeSpan
    Dim i, t As Integer

    For i = 0 To textBoxes1A.Count - 1
        Dim dateA, dateB As Date
        If Date.TryParse(textBoxes1A(i).Text, dateA) AndAlso Date.TryParse(textBoxes1B(i).Text, dateB) Then
            total = total.Add(dateB.Subtract(dateA))
            textBoxesTOT(t).Text = total.ToString()
            If i Mod 3 = 2 Then
                total = TimeSpan.Zero
                t += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**One final recommendation:** Try to always use meaningful names for your variables and controls. Avoid using things like `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, and `t` (`i` is fine here though *because it's used as the index of the `For` loop*).

Comment: Hi Ahmed Thanks for your reply and time.Your code works perfect. I will keep your recommendation in mind and try to avoid such names.

Comment: @ Ahmed, With this code i get HH:mm:ss is there a way to get only HH:mm or only HH?

Comment: @Raffab Replace `total.ToString()` with `total.ToString("hh\:mm")` or `total.ToString("hh")`, respectively. Note that it has to be `hh`; you can't use `HH` like what you would normally do with DateTime (however, `hh` _in the case of TimeSpan_ uses 24 hours format). Also, you have to use `\:` as `:` won't work with a TimeSpan. Refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) for more.

Comment: @ Ahmed, Can I still add code that empty textboxes are 00:00 in the sum?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to reset your `total` on every third run of your loop:

```
If i Mod 3 = 2 Then total = New TimeSpan(0) 'assuming that total is TimeSpan
```

That line should be placed at the end of a loop.